# VB obtener cursor que devuelve una funcion en postgresql

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, odbc

Estoy usando postgresql y vb, y quiero obtner en vb el resultado de una funcion que devuelve un cursor, pero solo he podido hacer que me devuelva el nombre del cursor, y no quiero eso, sino los datos del cursor.

Este es el codigo :

```
Sub BUSQUEDA(ByRef OBJ As Object, ByVal STR_VALOR As String, ByVal INT_TIPO As Integer, ByVal STR_OPERACION As String)
Dim CONECTION As New OdbcConnection
        Try

            CONECTION.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SEAU.My.MySettings.FARMACIA_ISABEL_DBConnectionString_64").ConnectionString + ";pwd=xxxxx"

            Dim COMMAND As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(" SELECT SP_BUSQUEDA_DGV('" + STR_VALOR + "'," + CStr(INT_TIPO) + ",'" + STR_OPERACION + "','CURSOR_BUSQ'); " +
                                                         " FETCH ALL IN ""CURSOR_BUSQ"";", CONECTION)

Dim DA As New OdbcDataAdapter
            Dim DT As New DataTable

            CONECTION.Open()

            DA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            DA.Fill(DT)

            OBJ = DT
            CONECTION.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If (CONECTION.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
                CONECTION.Close()
            End If

            Throw ex
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Los cursores son normalmente lentos e ineficientes, y sinceramente creo que no es posible usar uno desde vb.net. Simplemente haz tu consulta sin usar un cursor, y si solo quieres ir leyendo los datos secuencialmente usa un [`OdbcDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) en lugar de un `OdbcDataAdapter`. Además, es muy importante no componer tus queries concatenando cadenas. En lugar de eso, debes SIEMPRE usar queries parametrizadas para evitar Sql Injection.

Comment: hola,  muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Un favor me podrias explicar por codigo como seria sin usar un cursor, gracias

Comment: Si te fijas en el enlace que puse, pinchando en `OdbcDataReader`, ahi tienes un ejemplo de como se haría. Si despues de eso sigues teniendo dudas, me dices. Ten en cuenta que si es un procedimiento almacenado lo que tratas de consultar, debes poner en tu conection la propiedad `CommandType` a `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo vi el ejemplo, pero como seria un "select"  dentro de una funcion, y obtenerlo en vb ?. Porque ya vi un ejemplo de una funcion  que ejecuta un select que retorna una tabla ( que se define al principio de la funcion), pero no quisiera eso, porque en mi funcion la cantidad de columnas que devuelve puede variar, segun la condicion que se cumpla en mi funcion. Gracias